# How to convert CMSampleBufferRef/CIImage/UIImage into pixels e.g. uint8_t[]

Tags: c++, objective-c, image, c++11, avfoundation

I have input from captured camera frame as `CMSampleBufferRef` and I need to get the raw pixels preferably in C type `uint8_t[]`.
I also need to find the color scheme of the input image.

I know how to convert `CMSampleBufferRef` to `UIImage` and then to `NSData` with png format but I don`t know how to get the raw pixels from there. Perhaps I could get it already from` CMSampleBufferRef/CIImage`?

This code shows the need and the missing bits.
Any thoughts where to start?

```
int convertCMSampleBufferToPixelArray (CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer)
{
    // inputs
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:imageBuffer];
    CIContext *imgContext = [CIContext new];
    CGImageRef cgImage = [imgContext createCGImage:ciImage fromRect:ciImage.extent];
    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    NSData *nsData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(uiImage);
    

    // Need to fill this gap
    uint8_t* data = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
    ImageFormat format = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; // one of: GRAY8, RGB_888, YV12, BGRA_8888, ARGB_8888


    // sample showing expected data values
    // this routine converts the image data to gray
    //
    int width = uiImage.size.width;
    int height = uiImage.size.height;
    const int size = width * height;
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> new_data(new uint8_t[size]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        new_data[i] = uint8_t(data[i * 3] * 0.299f + data[i * 3 + 1] * 0.587f +
                          data[i * 3 + 2] * 0.114f + 0.5f);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pointers you can use to search for more info. It's nicely documented and you shouldn't have an issue.

```c
int convertCMSampleBufferToPixelArray (CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer) {
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    if (imageBuffer == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    // Get address of the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    uint8_t* data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    
    // Get size
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    // Get bytes per row
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

    // At `data` you have a bytesPerRow * height bytes of the image data
    
    // To get pixel info you can call CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType, ...
    // you can call CVImageBufferGetColorSpace and inspect it, ...
    
    // When you're done, unlock the base address
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

---

There're couple of things you should be aware of.

First one is that it can [be planar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/optimizing_image_processing_performance). Check the [`CVPixelBufferIsPlanar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456805-cvpixelbufferisplanar), [`CVPixelBufferGetPlaneCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456976-cvpixelbuffergetplanecount), [`CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456711-cvpixelbuffergetbytesperrowofpla), etc.

Second one is that you have to calculate pixel size based on [`CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456851-cvpixelbuffergetpixelformattype?language=objc). Something like:

```c
CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType(imageBuffer)

size_t pixelSize;
switch (pixelFormat) {
    case kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA:
    case kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB:
    case kCVPixelFormatType_32ABGR:
    case kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA:
        pixelSize = 4;
        break;
    // + other cases
}
```

Let's say that the buffer is not planar and:

- `CVPixelBufferGetWidth` returns 200 (pixels)
- Your pixelSize is 4 (calcuated bytes per row is 200 * 4 = 800)
- `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow` can return anything `>= 800`

In other words, the pointer you have is not a pointer to a contiguous buffer. If you need row data you have to do something like this:

```c
uint8_t* data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

// Get size
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

size_t pixelSize = 4; // Let's pretend it's calculated pixel size
size_t realRowSize = width * pixelSize;

size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);

for (int row = 0 ; row < height ; row++) {
    // bytesPerRow acts like an offset where the next row starts
    // bytesPerRow can be >= realRowSize
    uint8_t *rowData = data + row * bytesPerRow;
    
    // realRowSize = how many bytes are available for this row
    // copy them somewhere
}
```

You have to allocate a buffer and copy these row data there if you'd like to have contiguous buffer. How many bytes to allocate? [`CVPixelBufferGetDataSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1457195-cvpixelbuffergetdatasize?language=objc).

Comment: This looks like a right way. However, when executed then bytesPerRow=788 and width=480; Should not the bytesPerRow be dividable by width? What am I missing?

Comment: I found this "Each pixel is 4 bytes. Width is given in number of pixels, not number of bytes". Should not the bytesPerRow=4*width ?

Comment: See the updated answer, there's a lot of things you should be aware of.

Comment: Great. I've already set the videoOutput to kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA so the buffer is not planar anymore (first point). I guess the reason why CVPixelBufferGetDataSize returns 8 extra bytes is also explained in your answer that buffer size must not reflect the real data size (there can be extra bytes).

Comment: So my last thing is to convert the 4 BGRA bytes into 1 RGB (uint8_t) byte but this should only be matter of the color positions, right?

Comment: Yep, you have access to pixel data and you can do whatever you want with them.